# AD DC for domain could not be contacted

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dhcp, samba

We are using samba4 on Debian 8 as a AD DC and isc-dhcp on another Debian 8 machine as a DHCP router.
The problem is that if I set dhcp ip on a windows client I can't join the domain. If I add the AD DC ip on the windows client preferred DNS I can join the domain but the computer doesn't have internet access.

I think the problem is with the DHCP server. I would like to have all the windows clients on dynamic ip not on static.

/etc/network/interface for the domain server

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.1.1
    broadcast 10.10.1.255
    gateway 10.10.1.1
    dns-nameservers 10.10.1.100
    dns-search altfeldc.local
```

/etc/hosts for the domain server

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.10.1.100     altfeldc.altfel.local   altfeldc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/resolv.conf for domain server

```
nameserver 10.10.1.100
```

/etc/network/interface for the dhcp server

```
# WAN network adapter
auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set wan0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto wan0
iface wan0 inet manual

# WLAN network adapter
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    address 10.10.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.1.0
    broadcast 10.10.1.255
```

/etc/hosts for the dhcp server

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.10.1.1       altfeldhcp

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/resolv.conf for the dhcp server - 193.x.x.x and 213.x.x.x are from ISP

```
nameserver 193.231.252.1
nameserver 213.154.124.1
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf on dhcp server

```
ddns-update-style none;
log-facility local7;
authoritative;

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.10.1.255;
option routers 10.10.1.1;
option domain-name-servers 10.10.1.100, 193.231.252.1, 213.154.124.1;
option domain-name "altfel.local";
option netbios-name-servers 10.10.1.100;

subnet 10.10.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    interface wlan1;
    range 10.10.1.2 10.10.1.254;
    deny unknown-clients;
}

update-static-leases true;

host altfeldc {
  hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
  fixed-address 10.10.1.100;
{
# other hosts after this line...
```

dig command on domain server

```
root@altfeldc:~# dig altfel.local

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u1-Debian <<>> altfel.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21852
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;altfel.local.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
altfel.local.           900     IN      A       10.10.1.100

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.10.1.100#53(10.10.1.100)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 30 10:49:42 EEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

nslookup on windows client

```
C:\Users\admin>nslookup altfel.local
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.10.1.100

Name:    altfel.local
Address:  10.10.1.100
```

Domain join error

```
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location     (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain   Controller (AD DC) for domain "altfel.local":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.altfel.local

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate an AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when an AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

213.154.124.1
193.231.252.1
10.10.1.100

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

altfel.local
local
. (the root zone)
```